# Oembed for youtube

Tags: javascript, api, jquery

Do I need Developer's key for using oembed for youtube in my website?

The problems is that following code does not works, It does not returns to succes

```
 $.ajax({
                    url: "http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PVzljDmoPVs",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    timeout: 15000,
                    success: function (jo) {
                        if (jo) {
                            setIMg(jo.thumbnail_url);
                            setTitle(jo.title);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

But when i fire the url in the browser then it gives me the json:

> `{"provider_url": "http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/", "thumbnail_url": "http:\/\/i1.ytimg.com\/vi\/PVzljDmoPVs\/hqdefault.jpg", "title": "David Guetta - She Wolf (Falling To Pieces) ft. Sia", "html": "\u003ciframe width=\"480\" height=\"270\" src=\"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/PVzljDmoPVs?fs=1\u0026feature=oembed\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen\u003e\u003c\/iframe\u003e", "author_name": "davidguettavevo", "height": 270, "thumbnail_width": 480, "width": 480, "version": "1.0", "author_url": "http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/user\/davidguettavevo", "provider_name": "YouTube", "type": "video", "thumbnail_height": 360}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly no, you don't need a developer key to use the oembed endpoints of YouTube.

Secondly, YouTube doesn't support JSONP on its oEmbed endpoint, that's the reason your call fails. In order to fix it, you can use a third party oEmbed provider such as [reEmbed.me](http://reEmbed.me)

Here is the sample code:

```
var serviceUrl = "http://reembed.me/api/v1/OEmbed?url=";
var url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PVzljDmoPVs";
$.getJSON(serviceUrl + encodeURIComponent(url) + "&callback=?", null, function (jo) {
    if (jo) {
        setIMg(jo.thumbnail_url);
        setTitle(jo.title);
    }
});
```

Note that the link being passed is the actual video url, not the oembed endpoint link.

Answer (score 0):

No, We do not need any developer key to use oEmbed endpoints of any oEmbed providers.

[oEmbed](http://oembed.com/) spec supports two formats one is json and the other is xml type. oEmbed providers would provide response to oEmbed api in either one of the formats.

There is no format like `jsonp` according to the spec that's why you couldn't get proper response from the oEmbed provider like "youtube". Invoking the url with `type` query param as `json` should produce expected result

```
url: "http://www.youtube.com/oembed?type=json&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PVzljDmoPVs"
```

You can specify the `type` value as `json` or `xml` in request - else the provider would provider would respond with `json` by default.

oEmbed spec doesn't mention anything about JSONP support: So, youtube haven't provided support for JSONP I guess..

Anyways to access a cross site resource (CORS - Cross Origin resource sharing) the response header must contain `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` set else we can go with should go for default `jsonp` standard which youtube doesn't support.

I hope this [little hack on JSONP](https://cameronspear.com/blog/exactly-what-is-jsonp/) could solve our need. Else we can go for external libraries like [yuilibrary](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/io/).