# Oembed syntax error with jQuery ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, oembed

I am trying to get the response json of an oEmbed request. Heres the code:

```
var _url = 'http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http%3A//youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DM3r2XDceM6A&format=json';

$.ajax({
    url: _url,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(){
        alert(this.responseText);
    },
    error: function(){
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

The console throws the error:

> [Error] SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'. Parse error.
>       (anonymous function) (oembed, line 1)

**Update**

I have corrected the `dataType` property to `json`. That seems to have solved that problem. Now I am getting an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error.

Comment: It's because the URL is returning JSON, not JSONP. Set `dataType: 'json'`. Also note that `this.responseText` will not work, use the parameter provided to the `success` function to retrieve the data in the response. This is of course assuming you're not prevented from retrieving the data due to the Same Origin Policy

Comment: That seems to have solved that problem. Now Iam getting an Access-Control-Allow-Origin error.

Comment: That means you can't make the request to that endpoint via JS alone. There's nothing you can do about that one. See the question I marked as a duplicate for more information.

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12929249/oembed-for-youtube/44893308#44893308 - you may find it useful..